# Google Play Console Rejected My App Update and Said something about Full Description

Tags: dependencies, google-play, google-play-console, app-update

My app is live on google play store and i did some minor changes to the layout and updated some dependencies of
firebase, They rejected saying - **Your app appears to use popular brands, characters, and other assets associated with patterns of harmful behavior or high risk of abuse**.

[image: Mail from Playstore]

Comment: What is the description for your app?

Comment: In this app, If you're Creator( Youtube, TikTok, Facebook Page, Instagram Page, VMate etc.) or Advertiser and searching Social Media Platforms to Show your Ads then This app suits best to you, Create Account and you can easily find any Social Media Platforms account at one place, All you have to do is to choose the Creator from dropdown and choose How much Followers/Subscribers you want to show your ads to. And Creator will get directly all the Advertiser account at one place. (Direct Chat Option is Available)

Comment: Youtube, TikTok, Facebook Page, Instagram Page, VMate - One of these phrases you're not allowed to use.

Comment: Thank you, i am removing all of these names. And then i'll inform you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google doesn't allow you to write the name of another app in your app's description. Thus i just removed **Youtube, TikTok, Facebook Page, Instagram Page, VMate** these names and edit was success.